# Consulta com inner join

Tags: mysql

Preciso verificar se um dado na tabela1 esta representado na tabela2

Na `tabela1`

```
ID | NOME | PARCELAS | DATA | NF
```

Na `tabela2`

```
ID | VALOR | PARCELA | VENCIMENTO | NF
```

> Consulta SQL com INNER JOIN

Pode ser que esteja me equivocando querendo fazer a consulta com `inner join` o que eu preciso saber se a quantidade de lançamentos da `tabela2` e realmente a quantidade de parcelas informadas na coluna `parcelas` da `tabela1`, exemplo se na `tabela1` a coluna `parcelas` estiver informando 3 preciso saber se realmente existem 3 lançamentos na `tabela2`.

A consulta que realizei e' esta' mas não esta trazendo o que preciso.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tabela2` 
INNER JOIN tabela1 ON ftabela2.NF = 
tabela1.NF
WHERE fin_lancamentos.Qtde_Parcelas > 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o melhor jeito de fazer isso seria com uma *subquery* na condição `where` do SQL. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 T1 
WHERE T1.PARCELAS = (SELECT COUNT(T2.PARCELA) FROM tabela2 T2 WHERE T2.NF = T1.NF)
```

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que usar `LEFT JOIN` , ficaria assim:

```
SELECT a.NF, a.parcelas, COUNT(b.id) AS qtdeParcelas FROM tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ON a.NF = b.NF
GROUP BY a.NF;
```

Caso você queira trazer somente as que estão corretas pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT a.NF, a.parcelas, COUNT(b.id) AS qtdeParcelas FROM tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ON a.NF = b.NF
HAVING tabela1.parcelas = qtdeParcelas
GROUP BY a.NF;
```